# Help with the regEX

Tags: regex

I would like to have the regex to validate that user has entered any user name but not administrator. So that anything other than "administrator" is just fine.

Comment: Why do you need regex for this? Something along the lines of `username != "" && username != "administrator"` seems like it would fit your needs...

Comment: really i don't but that is really what puzzled me. Is it possible to write something like in regEx !administrator ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple string compare will do this job.

But if you want a regex You can use negative look-ahead assertion as:

```
^(?!administrator$).*$
```

[Rubular Link](http://www.rubular.com/r/dYJGcyi8uo)

You may want to replace `.*` with the regex to match a valid username based on allowed character and/or length requirements.

Comment: Wow, big lesson learned... i just can't afford to ignore regEx :) (its just so amazing). thank for nice handy link i will keep it with my MUST HAVE tool list.

Answer (score 1):

Use, Compare Validator. At value to Compare u write "administrator" and if not u continue. Hope it will work finr.